# Azure SQL sessions blocked in status PAGEIOLATCH_SH

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've got a Spring application with Hibernate that sporadically stops working because all 30 connections of its connection pool are blocked. While these connections were blocked, I executed a bunch of queries to find the cause.

1. Each connection executed the same join statement.
2. The execution plan of that join looks like that

[image]

3. This query

   SELECT *
   FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)

returns for each connection something like:

- status = suspended
- command = SELECT
- blocking_session_id = 0
- wait_type = last_wait_type = PAGEIOLATCH_SH
- wait_time = 3
- cpu_time = 12909
- total_elapsed_time = 3723943
- logical_reads = 7986970

4. The 3 indexes involved have a size of about 16GB (last one in the screenshot above), 1 GB and 500 MB respectively.
5. This is happening inside a sql database in an elastic pool with 24 vcores, Gen5, max data size 2418 GB
6. The resource monitor of that elastic pool looked reasonable (arrow indicates the correct time):

[image]

Anything else I could check? Any ideas what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting data on an increasing key (like an identity column) that means many parallel threads will be going after the last data page of that table if a good number of connections is trying to ingest data to the table, trying to add rows on that same data page.

If you put that table in memory (in-memory OLTP) you may not have a disk contention problem, but in this scenario that table is not in-memory so the disk contention is manifesting itself as pagelatch_ex wait.

Another option is to make the clustered index a GUID. That will make the insert distribute among all the data pages, but it may cause page splits.